# Possible to delete an object's specific row in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have model that creates several different rows. Like this...

```
class Myteam(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    QB = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    RB1 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    WR = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    TE = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    D = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    K = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
```

In my template, I'm looping through the rows and displaying them as html table rows. I've added a delete function to each row because I'd like the app's user to be able delete a player from their "Myteam" object. Problem is, I can only delete the entire object because there's only one id which is for the entire object. The template looks like this right now. Here's two rows as an example.

```
<tbody>
{% for t in team %}    
    <tr>  
        
        <td id="" > {{ t.QB }}  
             
            <a href="{% url 'delete_player' t.id %}">Delete</a>  
        </td> 
    
    <tr>

        <td> {{ t.RB1 }}  
             
            <a href="{% url 'delete_player' t.id %}">Delete</a>  
        </td> 
    
    </tr>

    <tr>
```

I did come across one possible solution here which suggested using {{ forloop.counter }} to assign individual id's to the row, but I can't get this to work how I would like.

Just in case, here's the views.py

```
def delete_player(request, id):
    player = Myteam.objects.get(id=id)
    player.delete() 
    return redirect('show')
```

I feel like there's probably a pretty basic solution to this but I'm new to django and am having trouble finding such answers. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so those model fields are database table *columns*, not rows. Instances of the model are table rows.

You don't delete columns, instead you set them to null. Your view could for example take the column name as a string argument:

```
def delete_player(request, id, col_name):
    player = Myteam.objects.get(id=id)
    setattr(player, col_name, None)
    player.save()
    return redirect('show')
```

Also since your fields are `CharField`s, it's best practice to not make them nullable (meaning, don't set `null=True`), but instead use an empty string `""` to indicate an unset value. This way you don't have two different values that indicate emptyness. Thus in the view you would use `setattr(player, col_name, "")`.

Comment: That does look like it makes sense. Actually, for passing the column name. I'm not quite sure how to do that. would the url look something like "path('delete_player/<int:id><str:cpl_name>', views.delete_player, name="delete_player")"?

Comment: It could also be a query parameter now that I think about it.